# How can I enforce Constructor method with Interface class?

Tags: c#

Constructor has not a generic name but the same name as class so there is a syntax problem to enforce them in interface class. What's the syntax then for something like this:

```
Interface IInterface {

    <class-name-of-implementer>(string param) {}
}
```

The problem I see with creating an initialize method is that client app of your framwork/library can just forget to call it ! Seems to me that if constructor was just named __Constructor like in some other languages that would be possible so it's not possible just because of syntax !

Syntax should not drive design but semantics.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, I'm afraid.

Generally speaking, you wouldn't be able to use such a constructor anyway - how would you expect to invoke it? You *can* enforce a parameterless constructor on a type parameter, like this:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : new()
```

but you can't specify any required parameters.

I've previously suggested that it would be useful to be able to specify static members (including constructors) in interfaces, *solely* for type constraints (and to use them the members in expressions based on those constrained type parameters). See [my blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. Your best bet would be

```
interface IInterface 
{
  void Initialize(string param);
}
```

where Initialize does some initialization work (if this is what you're after).

Comment: The problem I see with initialize is that you can just forget to call it ! Seems to me that if constructor was just named __Constructor like in other languages that would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are not allowed in interfaces.

A workaround would be to put an initialize() method in the constructor and do all the constructor related stuff here. Messy but that's all you can do.